# Power cut during Ubuntu upgrade to 10.04 - boots to command line, apt-get and dpkg do not work

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-10.04

I was upgrading Ubuntu to 10.04, when a tripswitch tripped, cutting power to the computer. When it was restarted, it booted into a command line prompt. Google tells me to try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This gets me **a lot** of output that ends with a list of packages. I can't tell you what the output is, as piping the output to `more`/`less` does not work (still just all scrolls by and moves to next prompt), and redirecting it to a file just results in an empty file.

Google also suggested:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This also didn't work.

Is a fresh install the only solution at this point?

Comment: if redirecting the output to a file results in an empty file try redirecting STDERR to STDOUT.. That might help.. Use this:
`$<command> 2>&1 | tee cmd_output.log`
This should redirect STDERR to STDOUT and capture it in cmd_output.log file. If we have the error message for either apt-get or dpkg command, we can try to fix it..

Answer (score 1):

are you able to access the `sources.list` ?

if so, modified it

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup

$ sudo kate /etc/apt/sources.list
```

find and replaced all instances of "karmic" with "lucid". I think you've done these steps.

Then, Update and upgraded again.

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This process took a long time but did produce an error relating to kdelibs5. The details are not so important, but was fixed using the following command `apt-get` straight up said to try this

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

If this part works for you, you can then resume your update. Again, using:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that, Fix other applications

```
$ sudo apt-get install parted
```

Then, reboot

```
$ sudo reboot
```

if you can't get it , fresh install will be better .

Comment: Doesn't work. Anything after sudo apt-get -f install just fails.

Comment: @Macha: But with what messages does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-minimal
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: apt-get refused to install anything. I had to reinstall in the end.